# symfony create user and role

Tags: php, symfony

My 2nd day in symfony :-) I created Entity, form and Controller "REGISTER USER". My form adds the user to the database but not its role.

I modeled on this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

DB role:

```
ID | NAME | ROLE
1 | user | ROLE_USER
2 | admin | ROLE_ADMIN
```

DB user_role

```
USER_ID | ROLE_ID
(EMPTY)
```

This is my code:

users

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
//other fields

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    //....
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }
    //....
}
```

Role

```
class Role implements RoleInterface{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

And piece of code Controller

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType);


    $form->handleRequest($Request);
    if($form->isValid()){
        $formData=$form->getData();
        if($formData['password']==$formData['repeatpassword']){
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $user = new User();
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            $user->setSalt(md5(time()));

            $pass = $encoder->encodePassword($formData['password'], $user->getSalt());
            $user->setEmail($formData['email']);
            $user->setPassword($pass);
            $user->setActive(1);
            $user->setName($formData['name']);
            $user->setSurname($formData['surname']);
            $user->setCountry($formData['country']);
            $user->setBirthdate($formData['birthdate']);
            $user->setCity($formData['city']);
            $user->setBirthdate($formData['birthdate']);
            $user->setAddress($formData['address']);
            $user->setPhone($formData['phone']);
            $user->setZipcode($formData['zipcode']);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

How I can add role to user? I want to give the id or name of the role in the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are up for a great start but here are the next steps you need to know/do:

[This documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) will show you how to get an entity from the database. [This documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities) will show you how to save a related entity.

`$user->setSalt(md5(time()));` is not secure; you should refer to
[this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password) to know how to generate the password properly in a secure way.

You should not bind each field manually instead you should follow [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) to know how to handle forms properly and [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object) to know how you can bind an entity to a FormType class.

Comment: My form and query that adds the user works ... I know it's not perfect, I'll work on this. Currently I have a problem with adding user role. My base user_role is empty after adding the user. The question is how can I improve the code to add in addition to the user and his roles.

Comment: @viko I would take care of what he said first and it'd make your life and ours easier by making it more simple to help you and making your problem less complex.

Comment: @viko your question and my answer have all the information you need to make your application work the way you want to. If you can't make sense out of the information provided then maybe you don't understand about how entities work in Symfony therefore I'd advise you to read the [documentation about Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Comment: @Thomas Potaire Thx. I think that should use twice 'persist()', such as an example http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities I was wondering why there are no examples on the Internet.

Comment: Yes, also line 18 of the example is important; by the way that example is also in my answer (I'd appreciate if you could upvote and/or accept the answer)